# iOS -- use instruments to mark when a method [or function] is called?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, instruments

I am running the time profiler in Instruments.  I need to know when a certain method is called.  Putting vertical lines in my trace at those times would be great.  Is there a way I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

If using Simulator is good enough, you might be able to use DTrace to do something. (So far as I know, it's only on Mac, not iOS.)